# _underscore loop in a template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I keep getting an error with this. I keep getting a syntax error:

> syntax error var _*p=[],print=function(){*_p.push.a... ');}return
>   __p.join('');

```
 <script id="product" type="text/template">  
      <p><span>items</span><span class='items'><%= _.each(info.items, function(books) { %> 
      <%= books.name + ",&nbsp" %>
      <% }); %></span></p>
    </script>
```

Anyone know why this error is happening. I have looked at some other people using this style and it seems correct but maybe I'm missing a symbol?

**Note: Fixed the issue.** 
My code had a `=` sign in the wrong place.

```
<%= _.each(info.items, function(books) { %>
```

should be:

```
<% _.each(info.items, function(books) { %>
```

Not sure why you need the `=` for some areas and not for others. Maybe someone can explain.
example in this area of the code I need to use a `=` sign :

`<%= books.name + ",&nbsp" %>`

Answer (score 3):

With the default settings, when you do `<%= variable %>` it just prints out the value of `variable`.

To evaluate (i.e. run a piece of Javascript code) you do `<% alert('something') %>`

Answer (score 1):

`<%= variable %>` is underscore shorthand for `<% print variable %>`